# Get text of of selected "li"

Tags: java, wicket

Say I have this code that I need my app to read the currently selected `li` text value using Wicket.

```
<ul class="selecttoggle dropdown-menu app-option" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#">None</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Markup</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">C#</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">HTML 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Java</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
</ul>
```

How do I get the value of the selected item in the `ul`?

Should the `wicket:id` be in the `ul` or each `li` tag?

Comment: Is this a javascript or java question?

Comment: How is this a wicket question? The ul doesn't even have a wicket:id attribute that would bind it to a widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ListView to populate the list

```
<ul class="selecttoggle dropdown-menu app-option" role="menu">
  <li wicket:id="list">
    <a href="#" wicket:id="link">
      <span wicket:id="label"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And in your populate item, you can do something with the string when the link is clicked

```
@Override
protected void populateItem(ListItem<String> _item)
{
  final String s = _item.getModelObject();
  AjaxLink link = new AjaxLink("link")
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)
    {
      doSomethingWithString(s);
    }
  };
  _item.add(link);
  link.add(new Label("label", s));
}
```